# Get last N rows from a particular place in pandas data frame based on a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dateset like

```
Sno change  date
0   NaN 2017-01-01
1   NaN 2017-02-01
2   NaN 2017-03-01
3   NaN 2017-04-01
4   NaN 2017-05-01
5   NaN 2017-06-01
6   NaN 2017-07-01
7   NaN 2017-08-01
8   0.0 2017-09-01
9   NaN 2017-10-01
10  NaN 2017-11-01
11  1   2017-12-01
12  NaN 2018-01-01
13  NaN 2018-02-01
```

I want to get the last 5 rows of "date" column in the data frame when the value in column "change" changes from NaN to anything else. So for this example, it will be divided into two sets:

```
Sno    date
3   2017-04-01
4   2017-05-01
5   2017-06-01
6   2017-07-01
7   2017-08-01
8   2017-09-01
```

and

```
Sno    date
6   2017-07-01
7   2017-08-01
8   2017-09-01
9   2017-10-01
10  2017-11-01
11  2017-12-01
```

Can anyone help me to get this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, with `loc` and `isna`:

```
#df=df.set_index('Sno')
idxs=df.index[~df.change.isna()]
sets=[df.loc[i-5:i,['date']] for i in idxs]
```

Output:

```
sets
[           date
 Sno            
 3    2017-04-01
 4    2017-05-01
 5    2017-06-01
 6    2017-07-01
 7    2017-08-01
 8    2017-09-01,

            date
 Sno            
 6    2017-07-01
 7    2017-08-01
 8    2017-09-01
 9    2017-10-01
 10   2017-11-01
 11   2017-12-01]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isna()` to check for `NaN values, then` np.where`to extract the locations of last row, finally,`np.r_` for creating slices:

```
s = df.change.isna()

valids = np.where(s.shift() & (~s))[0]

[df.iloc[np.r_[x-5:x]] for x in valid]
```

---

```
[   Sno  change        date
 3    3     NaN  2017-04-01
 4    4     NaN  2017-05-01
 5    5     NaN  2017-06-01
 6    6     NaN  2017-07-01
 7    7     NaN  2017-08-01,
     Sno  change        date
 6     6     NaN  2017-07-01
 7     7     NaN  2017-08-01
 8     8     0.0  2017-09-01
 9     9     NaN  2017-10-01
 10   10     NaN  2017-11-01]
```